# How do I ignore empty lines in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out how I ignore empty lines with spaces but no content. I have the following

```
^(\s*)SetEnv
```

Which matches what I am looking for fine, but it also matches empty lines with just spaces

So

```
SetEnv blah // matches
 // also matches
// doesn't match
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: PHP is what I am using.

Comment: You can use: `^ *SetEnv`

Comment: You should probably replace `*` with `+` (means one or more)

Comment: Can you post some code? This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Try:  ^(\s*)SetEnv.*$

Comment: Try `^(\s*?)SetEnv`? But yes, please post more PHP code. Also your example case is `SetEnv blah`, on the next line just a space, and on the last nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use the [m modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), you can use:

```
^(\h*)SetEnv
```

or

```
(?m)^(\h*)SetEnv
```

`\h` only matches horizontal white-spaces.

Comment: Never noticed the `\h` shorthand char class before. Thanks! +1